# How to use watchman in MacOS

Tags: react-native, macos, watchman

I already uninstalled watchman using:

`brew uninstall watchman`

But when I type `watchman` in the cmd I still get:

```
2023-01-06T20:49:27,810: [] while computing sockname: failed to create /opt/local/var/run/watchman/renatoperes-state: No such file or directory
```

I noticed that actually when I install watchman on by `brew uninstall watchman` the system is adding the lib in

`/usr/local/var/run/watchman/`

Does anyone have a clue? Thanks!

Comment: Your title sounds like you want to use watchman. Your question sounds like you cannot completely uninstall it. What are you trying to do please, and what is your question? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Still no progress with installation using brew (even reinstalled Homebrew).

However this seems to work (it's based on watchman formula):

```
cd /usr/local/var/run
sudo mkdir watchman
sudo chmod 042777 watchman
```

The watchman version correctly returns the version now:

```
{
   "version": "4.9.0"
}
```

And it seems to hot reload code in React Native.